# jms sending message on any server

Tags: jms, sendmessage

I want to write generic code for sending message on any jms server. so for that i thought if i have jndi.properties file then we can place server configuration in this file and we can access this file through the code but i am able to do this only for 'ActiveMQ Server'. Now i am facing problems to send the message on any other server like glassfish server or jboss server. can somebody help me to do this task.

Here is my code :

```
public class Producer 
{
   public Producer() throws JMSException, NamingException,IOException 
  {
   InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("my.jndi.properties");
   Properties jndiParamaters = new Properties();
   jndiParamaters.load(is);  
   Context jndi = new InitialContext(jndiParamaters); 
   ConnectionFactory conFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndi.lookup("connectionFactory");
   Connection connection; 
   connection = conFactory.createConnection();
try 
{
    connection.start();   
   Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);  
    Destination destination = (Destination) jndi.lookup("Myqueue"); 
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination); 
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Hello World!"); 
    producer.send(message);
    System.out.println("Sent message '" + message.getText() + "'");
} 
finally 
{
   connection.close();
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException 
{   
try
{
   BasicConfigurator.configure();
    new Producer();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}

}

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Spring JMS Template? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jms.html
It provides an abstraction layer to JMS and could probably help you when your implementation changes.